# what does “to take something far enough” mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Healy realised that **The 1975 had taken the idea of being a band in the postmodern internet age far enough.** Notes was a sprawling, 22-track, experimental album that reached for emo, UK garage, country, house and ambient music. It was existential, poignant, accomplished, a little self-indulgent and for a listener, honestly, exhausting. “I’m sure there are people that haven’t finished Notes,” Healy admits. For a band who had taken maximalism and experimentalism to such an extreme that it had become its own exoskeleton, The 1975 decided to do the most radical thing they could think of: just be a band again. 
> “The songs were written, and we went to a studio, and we produced them, and we recorded them. We’ve essentially not done that before, apart from the first album,” explains Healy. “You can try and figure out what I mean without this sounding kind of pretentious or wanky, but it’s kind of doing an impression of The 1975. Because as much as The 1975 has gone everywhere, kids know what The 1975 is, do you know what I mean?” They were no longer being clinical about music, a necessary component of creating the last two records. Some of these songs were recorded in one or two takes. “I’ve always wanted to make something very, very intimate and something that allows you to be witness to a moment,” Healy says.

(source: https://www.rollingstone.co.uk/music/features/the-1975-being-funny-in-a-foreign-language-new-album-interview-19940/)

I’d like to understand “to take something far enough” in this context.
According to an online dictionary, there’s  the expression “to take something too far ( to do something to an excessive degree)”.
But if you say ‘far enough’ like in this sentence, instead of ‘too far’, does it mean that you do something to *almost* an excessive degree?

I’d appreciate any help from native speakers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you take something far enough, you take it as far as is sensible or appropriate, but no further. Clearly, if you went much further, the degree would be excessive.

Comment: "far enough" also means "sufficient and no more"

Comment: What Michael and Peter said, and in the context, it could also mean, "as far as I felt like taking it".